# Matplotlib math text doesn't render in legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm having an issue with math text in a legend. I could swear it used to work, and it certainly works on another machine. And math text seems to work fine in other plotting scripts on this machine.

Basically, I have a figure made up of a bunch of stacked subplots. My legend is nominally attached to the first axis, but the handles and labels are unassociated with what's actually in the plots.

I make a list of handles and a list of labels.

All of the handles are `matplotlib.lines.Line2D`s. All of the labels use math text, e.g. `r'%.2f$\,$s' % (arg)`, or `r'$\mathbf{%.2f\,s}$' % (arg)`.

Here is relevant code:

```py
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
matplotlib.rcParams['mathtext.fontset'] = 'stix'
matplotlib.rcParams['font.family'] = 'STIXGeneral'
matplotlib.rcParams['legend.fancybox'] = False
matplotlib.rcParams['axes.titlepad'] = 10

...

ax00.legend(handles=handles,
            labels=labels,
            loc='upper left',
            bbox_to_anchor=(1.015, 1.035),
            fontsize=20,
            ncol=4,
            columnspacing=-1.5)
```

But then I get:

```
ValueError: 
\\mathbf{1.00\\,s}
^
Unknown symbol: \, found '\'  (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)
```

What I don't get is why this used to work, and why it works in other scripts. Is there an issue with legend labels when they're not related to something being plotted?

I haven't touched my environment am using the same version of matplotlib on this machine as on the one where this script works.

**EDIT** More error information

The full error output doesn't point to anything in my script, but the `legend` call is what triggers it. The first error line is:

```
  File "C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\pemdas\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mathtext.py", line 2598, in parse
    result = self._expression.parseString(s)
```

Then a bunch of stuff from pyparsing.py, followed by:

```
  File "C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\pemdas\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mathtext.py", line 2768, in unknown_symbol
    raise ParseFatalException(s, loc, "Unknown symbol: %s" % c)

ParseFatalException: Unknown symbol: \


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\pemdas\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\formatters.py", line 341, in __call__
    return printer(obj)
```

Then a bunch of matplotlib stuff, finally:

```
  File "C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\pemdas\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mathtext.py", line 2603, in parse
    str(err)]))

ValueError: 
\\mathbf{1.00\\,s}
^
Unknown symbol: \, found '\'  (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)
```

Comment: Could you post the error line here? It works [fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCjhF.png) on matplotlib 3.3.0 with [this](https://pastebin.com/nLhaN6jN) example.

Comment: The error line is the `ax00.legend`. But the ValueError is whichever is the first label in `labels`.

Comment: See my recent edit for more error info